# Set Origin "Origin to Geometry" stacks objects to one point in render

Tags: rendering, objects

So I started with the can selected in the red and added two array modifiers and I wanted to rotate the lid on each can, but since the origin point is set to the original can, it rotates relative to the can.

[image]

To fix this I selected every can and did *"Set Origin Point to Geometry"* which fixed the lid issue but after I set the origin point to geometry, it stacks all objects to the same object  on which the array modifier was used.

**This is the Render Output before applying Origin to Geometry:**

[image]

**This is the Render Output after applying Origin to Geometry:**
[image]

I am using Cycles but same thing is happening in Eevee also.

Comment: This looks like what would happen if you used "Set Geometry to Origin", are you sure you didn't accidentally do that ?

Comment: If you have a keyframe on the original model, then, every object will have it. So if you hit the render button every origin (with their mesh) will go to the same location as is shown on the picture.